# How to use AMSI_UAC_REQUEST_TYPE?

Tags: windows, security, uac, antivirus

Recently I implemented an [Antimalware Scan Interface (AMSI) provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/amsi/antimalware-scan-interface-portal) to intercept script execution, and scan script content before it executed. I based my code on the Microsoft sample AMSI provider. ([Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/AmsiProvider)).

In [`amsi.h`](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/9b69fd26ac0c7d0b83d378dba01080e93349c2ed/Include/10.0.10240.0/um/amsi.h#L106) I found `AMSI_UAC_REQUEST_TYPE` enum with very interesting fields:

```
typedef enum AMSI_UAC_REQUEST_TYPE
{
    AMSI_UAC_REQUEST_TYPE_EXE   = 0,
    AMSI_UAC_REQUEST_TYPE_COM   = 1,
    AMSI_UAC_REQUEST_TYPE_MSI   = 2,
    AMSI_UAC_REQUEST_TYPE_AX    = 3,
    AMSI_UAC_REQUEST_TYPE_MAX   = 4
}   AMSI_UAC_REQUEST_TYPE;
```

But I can't understand how to utilize it. Which callback should I use to intercept UAC request?